# Synchronisation across multiple servers?

Tags: thread-safety, client-server, load-balancing

I had an interesting discussion with a friend recently and we were talking about a client server architecture system where the server side was actually many servers (for load balancing). On a single server, I can see how thread safety can be achieved when many clients try to update the state of the system but how is this achieved in a multi-server load balanced environment? Having a single server acting as a gate to the multi-server load balancing farm that has the responsibility for thread safety seems like it would create a choke point and negate the load balancing features.

Can anyone explain how this would be achieved?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different techniques to ensure thread safety across multiple serves. One relies on the  [Thread Pool Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern) another one on the virtualization of server farms.